# How to read Facebook JSON results in PHP

Tags: php, json, facebook-graph-api, request, file-get-contents

Sorry - this will be a bit poorly worded.

My code `fbid` is from a form. I what to know how to get and display parts on whats been requested by `file_get_contents()`.

```
<?php echo $_POST["fbid"]; ?>
<?php $x=$_POST['fbid'];?>
<?php echo file_get_contents("http://graph.facebook.com/" . $x); ?>
```

See the code below that's what the `file_get_contents()` displays like:

```
{
  "id": "4",
  "name": "Mark Zuckerberg",
  "first_name": "Mark",
  "last_name": "Zuckerberg",
  "link": "http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/zuck",
  "username": "zuck",
  "gender": "male",
  "locale": "en_US"
}
```

How can I echo the fields `name` and `gender` from this string?

```
Name: Their name 
Gender: Their gender
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `json_decode()` to parse the data. The Facebook graph search results are returned in JSON format, so you just need to parse them and then they are accessible.

```
<?php

$data = file_get_contents("http://graph.facebook.com/" . $x);
$array = json_decode($data, true);

echo $array['name'];
echo $array['gender'];

?>
```

Take a look at the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Comment: Thanks i was looking at json before but didn't have $data :) thanks heaps really helped me alot.